# How to fix List<String> is not subtype of String error?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I keep on getting the error `List<String> is not a subtype of String` , if in my model I've already declared that I want to collect a List for certain fields within the model?

So, below is code for my data model :

```
class DataModel{
  String ID;
  List<String> name;
  List<String> type;
  List<String> images;
  
  DataModel({
   required this.ID,
   required this.name,
   required this.type,
   required this.images,
  
   });

    factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      ID: json['ID'] ?? '' ,
      name: json['name'] ?? '' ,
      type: List<String>.from(json['type']??[]) ,
      images:  List<String>.from(json['images']??[]) , 
    );
  }
   Map<String, Object> toJsonAdd() => {
        "ID":ID,
        "name": name,
        "images": images,
        "type": type,
        
      };

}
```

Now, below is where I'm using the model to pass data to db:

```
 List<String> nameList =[];
  List<String> typeList =[];
  List<String> imageList =[];

 add(DataModel dataModel) async {
    await ref.read(dataProvider).addData(dataModel).then((success) {});
  }

 DataModel dataModel = dataModel(
         ID: '',
         name: nameList.toList(),
         mealTypes: filteredMealTypes.toList(),
              priceOfType: filteredPriceMealType.toList(),
            );
            add(menuModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `database` is not capable of storing `List` of `String` or any kind of `List` at all, that is why it keeps producing same error.

Try to convert your `list` in to `String` and store it in `database`.

You can use something like `dart:convert` which has method something like `jsonEncode` and pass the list of string to it and it will convert it  to string.

Also on retrieving data you can again use jsonDecode to convert you string list to dart list type.